# JsonDeserializationSchema.deserialize causes NullPointerException

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to read a `.jsonl` files using Flink.

Following the [official guide](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/json/), however, I encountered `NullPointerException`.

Data File:

```
{"name": "jimmy", "age":  10}
{"name": "tommy", "age":  11}
{"name": "marry", "age":  12}
```

Flink App:

```java
public class FlinkApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        build(env);
        env.execute();
    }

    private static void build(StreamExecutionEnvironment environment) {

        Path in_path = new Path("hdfs://.../people.jsonl");

        FileSource<String> source = FileSource
                .forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineInputFormat(), in_path)
                .build();
        var dsSource = environment
                .fromSource(
                        source,
                        WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
                        "text source");

        // this line initialize the format
        // vvv
        JsonDeserializationSchema<People> jsonFormat = new JsonDeserializationSchema<>(People.class);
        dsSource
                // this line try to parse each line text into object
                // vvv
                .flatMap((FlatMapFunction<String, People>) (s, c) ->
                   c.collect(jsonFormat.deserialize(s.getBytes())))
                .returns(People.class)
                .addSink(new StdoutSink<>("json"));
    }


}

class StdoutSink<T> implements SinkFunction<T> {
    private String name;

    StdoutSink(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(T value, Context context) throws Exception {
        String b = String.format("%s: %s%n", name, value);
        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

Traceback:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.flink.formats.json.JsonDeserializationSchema.deserialize(JsonDeserializationSchema.java:69) ~[flink-json-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at my.flink.play.FlinkApp.lambda$build$29a9905b$1(FlinkApp.java:34) ~[flink-java-play-all.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFlatMap.processElement(StreamFlatMap.java:47) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask$AsyncDataOutputToOutput.emitRecord(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:313) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.source.SourceOutputWithWatermarks.collect(SourceOutputWithWatermarks.java:110) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.source.SourceOutputWithWatermarks.collect(SourceOutputWithWatermarks.java:101) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceRecordEmitter.emitRecord(FileSourceRecordEmitter.java:45) ~[flink-connector-files-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceRecordEmitter.emitRecord(FileSourceRecordEmitter.java:35) ~[flink-connector-files-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:143) ~[flink-connector-files-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:385) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:542) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:831) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:780) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:914) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
```

One divergence from the official guide is that I am using `JsonDeserializationSchema` literally by invoking `JsonDeserializationSchema#deserialize` method, instead of registering it to a Source (FileSource does not have such method to register a `JsonDeserializationSchema`), something like:

```java
KafkaSource.<SomePojo>builder()
  .setValueOnlyDeserializer(jsonFormat)
```

Later, I switch to use the humble `ObjectMapper` to perform JSON parsing:

```java
public class FlinkApp {
    private static void build(StreamExecutionEnvironment environment) {

        Path in_path = new Path("hdfs://.../people.jsonl");

        FileSource<String> source = FileSource
                .forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineInputFormat(), in_path)
                .build();
        var dsSource = environment
                .fromSource(
                        source,
                        WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
                        "text source");


//      use an ObjectMapper
//      vvv
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        dsSource
//               ObjectMapper#readValue to parse json string
//               vvv
                .flatMap((FlatMapFunction<String, People>) (s, c) -> 
                   c.collect(mapper.readValue(s.getBytes(), People.class)))
                .returns(People.class)
                .addSink(new StdoutSink<>("json"));
    }

}
```

This time I can see that parsing is done without error.

Does the call site have any impact on the behavior of `JsonDeserializationSchema#deserialize`, meaning my literal usage is a no-no but it must be used by "[connector that supports the DeserializationSchema](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/json/#json-format)"? Or it is something else that causes the  `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `JsonDeserializationSchema`, then you need to call its `.open()` method. So in that case you should have a real class that implements `RichFlatMapFunction`, and create the schema/call its open() method in your class's `open()` method.

Comment: Interesting. This is really not explicit if I can only learn from the official guide.
Is there any downside to use a plain `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: I don't know - e.g. I haven't compared performance, error handling, etc.